# CakePHP View URLs case-sensitive on one server, not another... why?

Tags: php, cakephp, case-sensitive

So I'm working on a CakePHP app, and had this line in one of my controllers:

```
$this->render('/vids/index');
```

It was working fine in MAMP. But on my live site (on MediaTemple) the controller couldn't find the view. After nearly pulling my hair out, I changed the line to this:

```
$this->render('/Vids/index');
```

And it worked.

Zuh? What could account for one system being case sensitive, and another not? My assumption is that this isn't a Cake issue, but I'm so baffled, I have no idea what's causing the discrepancy.

Comment: one has to distinguish between urls called via browser and internal render calls (which you should not call "urls"). For urls visible to the user it should not be Vids (uppercase) - I think one should stick to lowercase "vids" and under_scored_action names for urls to keep things simple (especially with custom routes etc this would get out of hand really fast!). but in your case you are calling actual layout/view "files" from your templates - therefore the uppercase as correct approach.

Comment: Makes sense! And you're right... URL was the wrong term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply because the 2nd line (uppercase Vids) is correct for a 2.0 app. And I guess there are differences between OSX (guess that from you using MAMP) and the servers OS you deploy the app on.

And why do you call render() manually? If you access /vids from the web it should automatically route to VidsController::index() and the controller will auto pick the right view.

Stands Vids for videos? Thats a horrible name. Abbreviations in code suck hard, if you want to rely on /vids for the URL use the router to rewrite that url.

Comment: I'm calling the index view manually because I have two actions that use the exact same view/code. They're responding to an ajax call, and would rather not duplicate things. Also, I'm the only one editing the code, and "vids" works for me. I mean, you knew what it meant! :P Thanks for the answer. I guess the Mac OS is just more forgiving.

Comment: FWIW, I've simplified my controller, and am now using one action, with no "hacks."